# How to solve missing bean references in Hybris' cuppytrail project?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

While following the instructions in cuppy-trail: [Testing the DAO topic](https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/7454bfb78cc948fda50c30714e37694a.html#loio7454bfb78cc948fda50c30714e37694a), I am getting the below exceptions. I have followed the instructions to the book, I have included `<context:component-scan base-package="de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail" />` in the `cuppytrail-spring.xml`. Pls suggest how to resolve the error. All 3 tests are failing.

Below are the `DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest` and `DefaultStadiumDAO`

```
public class DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest extends ServicelayerTransactionalTest
{
    /** As this is an integration test, the class (object) being tested gets injected here. */
    @Resource(name = "stadiumDAO")
    private StadiumDAO stadiumDAO;

    /** Platform's ModelService used for creation of test data. */
    @Resource
    private ModelService modelService;
    ....
}
```

***DefaultStadiumDAO :***

```
@Component(value = "stadiumDAO")
public class DefaultStadiumDAO implements StadiumDAO
{
  @Autowired
   private FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService;
    ....
}
```

***Error:***

```
WARN  [main] (junit) [ComposedTypeEJBImpl] missing jalo class 'com.hybris.backoffice.jalo.user.BackofficeRole' for item type 'BackofficeRole' - trying supertype class instead
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Starting test class de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest
INFO  [Task-junit-poll] (junit) [DefaultModelConverterRegistry] loading model converters: 
INFO  [Task-junit-poll] (junit) [DefaultModelConverterRegistry]     pre-fetch mode:default
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Starting test method testFindStadiums_EmptyStringParam(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest)
ERROR [main] (junit) [ServicelayerBaseTest] error fetching bean stadiumDAO : No bean named 'stadiumDAO' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'stadiumDAO' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:272) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest$1.doWith(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:66) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:605) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:585) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.autowireProperties(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:51) [classes/:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.prepareApplicationContextAndSession(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:42) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner$TenantActivationNotAllowedRunBefores.evaluate(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.run(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
ERROR [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Test method testFindStadiums_EmptyStringParam(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest) failed!!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: test DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest is not properly initialized - missing bean references [stadiumDAO]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.autowireProperties(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:86) ~[classes/:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.prepareApplicationContextAndSession(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:42) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner$TenantActivationNotAllowedRunBefores.evaluate(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.run(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Finished test method testFindStadiums_EmptyStringParam(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest) in 9 seconds
INFO  [main] (junit) [OpenDBConnectionRunListener] Currently still open DB connection: 0
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Starting test method stadiumDAOTest(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest)
ERROR [main] (junit) [ServicelayerBaseTest] error fetching bean stadiumDAO : No bean named 'stadiumDAO' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'stadiumDAO' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:272) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest$1.doWith(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:66) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:605) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:585) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.autowireProperties(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:51) [classes/:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.prepareApplicationContextAndSession(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:42) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner$TenantActivationNotAllowedRunBefores.evaluate(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.run(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
ERROR [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Test method stadiumDAOTest(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest) failed!!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: test DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest is not properly initialized - missing bean references [stadiumDAO]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.autowireProperties(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:86) ~[classes/:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.prepareApplicationContextAndSession(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:42) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner$TenantActivationNotAllowedRunBefores.evaluate(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.run(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Finished test method stadiumDAOTest(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest) in 7 seconds
INFO  [main] (junit) [OpenDBConnectionRunListener] Currently still open DB connection: 0
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Starting test method testfindStadiums_NullParam(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest)
ERROR [main] (junit) [ServicelayerBaseTest] error fetching bean stadiumDAO : No bean named 'stadiumDAO' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'stadiumDAO' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:272) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest$1.doWith(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:66) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:605) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:585) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.autowireProperties(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:51) [classes/:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.prepareApplicationContextAndSession(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:42) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner$TenantActivationNotAllowedRunBefores.evaluate(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.run(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
ERROR [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Test method testfindStadiums_NullParam(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest) failed!!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: test DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest is not properly initialized - missing bean references [stadiumDAO]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.autowireProperties(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:86) ~[classes/:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerBaseTest.prepareApplicationContextAndSession(ServicelayerBaseTest.java:42) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner$TenantActivationNotAllowedRunBefores.evaluate(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.run(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Finished test method testfindStadiums_NullParam(de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest) in 6 seconds
INFO  [main] (junit) [OpenDBConnectionRunListener] Currently still open DB connection: 0
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener] Finished (failed) test class de.hybris.platform.cuppytrail.daos.impl.DefaultStadiumDAOIntegrationTest
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener]   Total run time: 0d 00h:00m:24s:328ms
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener]   Total tests count: 3
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener]   Failed tests count: 3
INFO  [main] (junit) [LogRunListener]   Ignored tests count: 0
INFO  [main] (junit) [ClassLoaderOverviewRunListener] Loaded class count: 10195 diff: 434
INFO  [main] (junit) [ClassLoaderOverviewRunListener] Total loaded class count: 10195 diff: 434
INFO  [main] (junit) [ClassLoaderOverviewRunListener] Unloaded class count: 0 diff: 0
shutting down hybris registry..
INFO  [Thread-5] [DefaultClusterNodeManagementService] Unregistering assigned cluster node id 0...
```

Comment: I guess I figured out what's happening. Seems that the application context was not loaded, hence the issue. Having the /resources on the classpath did solve the problem, however, I am facing different error now. Two out of three tests have passed. Below is the most recent error:ERROR [Task-junit-poll] (junit) [DefaultTaskService] Caught exception while polling pending tasks.
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelTypeNotSupportedException: No converter registered for source type ComposedType
 at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.DefaultModelConverterRegistry.g

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue because I am using IntelliJ 17, however with eclipse it works!! is the same configuration but something with the spring configuration on IntelliJ dont allow it works, so... alternatives:

1) go on with eclipse :(
2) if you are using IntelliJ, you need add the resouce folder or at least your cuppytrail-spring.xml to your resource test wich you would see in project structure, you could duplicate this, the problem is IntelliJ on its *.iml is not able to find this file and dont get this context.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The following steps work for me.

1. ant clean all
2. Right click on module in Project view/ Rebuild module
   'cuppytrail'
3. File/ Refresh project

InteliJ Idea 2017.2 + Hybris integration plugin 6.3 ([plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525-hybris-integration))